# Plotting of Lorenz curves

Tags: plotting

I need some help in creating a Lorenz plot of Weibull distribution with pdf given by,

```
w[λ_, β_] := 
 ProbabilityDistribution[β/λ*(x/λ)^(β - 1)*E^-(x/λ)^β, {x, 0, ∞}, 
  Assumptions -> λ > 0 && β > 0]

PDF[w[λ, β], x]
```

for `λ=2, β=5`

Please could someone help me?

Comment: What's a Lorenz plot?

Comment: I assume you mean this? [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_curve) it is always a good idea to give a reference or link for such things.

Comment: I recommend that you use the built-in distributions as much as possible rather than `ProbabilityDistribution` For example, your distribution is just `WeibullDistribution[β, λ]`

Answer (score 5):

```
h[λ_, β_, q_] = Integrate[InverseCDF[w[λ, β], x], {x, 0, q}, 
  Assumptions -> And[DistributionParameterAssumptions @ w[λ, β], 1 >= q > 0]]
```

> ```
>  λ (Gamma[1 + 1/β] - Gamma[1 + 1/β, - Log[1 - q]])
> ```

```
lorenzC[λ_, β_, q_] := h[λ, β, q]/h[λ, β, 1]

lorenzC[λ, β, q]
```

> ```
> (Gamma[1 + 1/β] - Gamma[1 + 1/β, -Log[1 - q]])/Gamma[1 + 1/β]
> ```

(Note the independence of `lorenzC` from the first argument.)

```
ParametricPlot[{{t, t}, {t, lorenzC[1, 1, t]}, {t, lorenzC[1, 2, t]}, 
 {t, lorenzC[1, 3, t]}, {t, lorenzC[1, 4, t]}}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{None, "1", "2", "3", "4"}, LegendLabel -> "β"], 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you kglr.  But I am not getting the output, when I tried the above code with a distribution which is not inbuilt, having form L[\[Alpha]_, \[Lambda]_, \[Beta]_] := 
 ProbabilityDistribution[(E^(-\[Lambda]*
      x - (\[Beta]*
       x)^\[Alpha])/(1 + \[Lambda])*(\[Alpha]*\[Lambda]*(\[Beta]*
         x)^\[Alpha] + \[Alpha]*\[Beta]*(1 + \[Lambda])*(\[Beta]*
         x)^(\[Alpha] - 1) + \[Lambda]^2*(1 + x))), {x, 
   0, \[Infinity]}, 
  Assumptions -> \[Lambda] >= 0 && \[Alpha] > 0 && \[Beta] >= 0]